# Displaying toast at a given offset

Tags: c#, android, monodevelop, offset, toast

I am having trouble displaying a toast at a given offset in a Google Maps application for Android.

Here is my code:

```
    static public void DisplayCustomToast (Context displayContext, string stringText, int offsetX, int offsetY)
    {
        Toast toast = new Toast(displayContext);
        toast.SetText(stringText);
        toast.SetGravity (GravityFlags.Top, offsetX, offsetY);
        toast.Show();
    }
```

When the emulator starts up, and I try and execute this code from the onCreate method via:

```
DisplayCustomToast(this, "test", -30, 50);
```

The application stops working totally and the cell phone main background is shown.

Can I please have some help to display a custom toast at a given offset for Android.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to do this

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, -30, 50);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
toast.SetGravity (GravityFlags.Top, 0, 0);
```